# Highly available but consistent id generator

Tags: architecture

Question to the system design experts here.

If I want to create highly-available token id generator that does incrementally generates tokens and no two instances MUST generate the same token id. Then how do you do it?

Comment: check out uuid generators

Comment: Are you interested in just the software side, or the infrastructure side as well?  Who will be consuming this service and from where (e.g. internet facing or private)?  Do you need an "on-premise" local service or is using cloud-based platforms ok?  Do you have any technical constraints or preferred technology?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.